# Answering a question multiple times: where to draw the line

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

When answering many of the complex questions on Stack Overflow, there is often more than one correct answer, but where is the line drawn between answering a question multiple times, and just adding an alternative solution in the same answer.  The "Add Another Answer" button is there for a reason, but where should the line be drawn?

Comment: Short answer: whenever you have a second answer that is clearly distinct from a previous answer. Especially in those two answers might give conflicting/mutually-exclusive solutions; users can vote on them separately to give a clearer picture of which solution the community values more.